# Styling image title attributes as a caption?

Tags: css, attributes, cross-browser, title

[NEW]

From my findings, either way i can't use the "after or :before as it's not how my function will run. My update is that when you click on a link the div appears with the relevant image and title and the title is now stored in the caption-overlay div.

How do i get that title information to display IN the div?

Here is my updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/SGktV/26/

[OLD]
I have the following code in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/SGktV/25/

That when you click on a link a hidden div fades in the image with the src and title attributes. My only concern is i know you can style the title attribute using :before and :after but i know that they do not work in IE 8. Has anyone found a solution or is there an alternative method i can use to show a caption related to the link clicked?

```
 content: attr(title);
```

Hope my code helps, Thanks!

Comment: `i know that they do not work in IE 8` :before and :after work just fine in IE8.

Comment: So from this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.aspx and if i use this method: http://cssdeck.com/labs/awesome-image-captions-with-css i should be ok? Just like to check as IE is a right nightmare isnt it!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

IE8 only supports the content property if a !DOCTYPE is specified.

---

but you use `content` with [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

you can use CSS3 with CSS3 Pie And it works in IE.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Read through the documentation and not really sure how to implement this into what i have? I assume it would ready something like content: attr(title); but unsure of where to apply the .htc if this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this without using :before and :after by doing this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SGktV/28/

Basically, i changed my line in my jQuery to read:

```
$("#hiddenPanel #caption-overlay").text($(this).attr("data-title"));
```

and added div tags in under the image tag:

```
 `<div id="caption-overlay"></div>`
```

Is this the right way to do this?